# Transfer matplotlib savefig .png to dest folder

Tags: python, matplotlib, shutil

I always get the error saying:

"raise Error("Cannot move a directory '%s' into itself"
shutil.Error: Cannot move a directory '/Users/mattbecute/Desktop/Valuable Projects/Webscrapingprojects/CovidMonitor/Covid Pie Charts' into itself '/Users/mattbecute/Desktop/Valuable Projects/Webscrapingprojects/CovidMonitor/Covid Pie Charts/Worldwide/November/'."

This is the code:

```
def transferPhoto(country):
    source = "/Users/mattbecute/Desktop/Valuable Projects/Webscrapingprojects/CovidMonitor/"
    destination = "/Users/mattbecute/Desktop/Valuable Projects/Webscrapingprojects/CovidMonitor/Covid Pie Charts/" + country.capitalize() + "/November/" 
    files = os.listdir(source)
    for f in files:
            if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ('.png'):
                    shutil.move(source + f, destination)
```

This function is about transferring the matplotlib pie chart(.png) that is saved in the current folder, and transferring it to its country filename then to the current Month, which is November.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you didn't design your if-case very well; check what happens if you run these two lines:

```
if "" in ".png":
    print("yep")
```

So either you change your if case to something more robust like

```
if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.png':
```

or at least switch the comparison around:

```
if ".png" in os.path.splitext(f)[1]:
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my problem. The second one worked really well. Thank you, again.